# How to fetch infinispan cache statistics in wildfly?

Tags: java, hibernate, caching, wildfly, infinispan

I am trying to fetch the statistics with jboss-cli

```
[standalone@localhost:9990 /] /subsystem=infinispan/cache-container=hibernate/local-cache=entity:read-attribute(name=statistics-enabled) 
{
    "outcome" => "success",
    "result" => true
}
```

That looks good but all actual statistics attributes do not return a value.

```
[standalone@localhost:9990 /] /subsystem=infinispan/cache-container=hibernate/local-cache=entity:read-attribute(name=number-of-entries)
{"outcome" => "success"}
```

The configuration in persistence.xml is:

```
<property name="hibernate.generate_statistics" value="true" />
<property name="hibernate.cache.infinispan.statistics" value="true"/>
<property name="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache" value="true" />
```

and in standalone.xml:

```
<cache-container name="hibernate" module="org.infinispan.hibernate-cache" statistics-enabled="true">
  <local-cache name="entity" statistics-enabled="true">
    <transaction locking="OPTIMISTIC" mode="NON_XA"/>
    <object-memory size="10000"/>
    <expiration max-idle="100000"/>
  </local-cache>
<!-- ... -->
</cache-container>
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that "resolve-expressions=true" helps:

```
/subsystem=infinispan/cache-container=hibernate/local-cache=entity/:read-attribute(name=number-of-entries,resolve-expressions=true,include-defaults=false)
{
"outcome" => "success",
"result" => undefined
}
```

It is consistent with that I see in jConsole -> WidlFly CLI tab.
But this path does not yield real Hibernate statistics that I can see in MBeans tab, so it does not completely answer your question.